# What grease should I use for an aftermarket cylinder valve (Moen)

Tags: faucet

We've a Moen faucet for the kitchen sink. Years, maybe decades old. The faucet was dripping last year so I replaced the cylinder with a Moen cylinder. Solved the leak but the handle would not stay up in the on position.  Returned the Moen cylinder.  Bought an aftermarket cylinder from Home Depot.  Handle stayed up.  Now, a year later, the faucet is very very difficult to turn on, as if the cyclinder needs to be re-greased.

What type of grease is compatible?

EDITs:

1) the cylinder looks like this: http://www.homedepot.com/p/100051867

2) found a possible duplicate:
[What can I use to lubricate a new kitchen faucet no longer turns?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2323)

Answer (score 1):

Any "Plumber's Grease" will lubricate the moving parts. Plumber's Grease is silicone based so it wont dissolve in water and it is viscous enough that it will remain were it is applied.

Comment: The plumber's grease that is pure silicone will do the job. It comes in a tiny  round container.